# Resetting Sony VAIO to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio, windows-activation, refresh

I have a Sony VAIO SVF15N17SNS or in other markets its known as SVF15N17CXB model that came with Windows 8 Single Language Pre -Installed.I upgraded it to Windows 8.1 Single language from Windows Store and there was no need to activate windows it took the windows 8 product key automatically.

Things were fine for long but few days back I noticed that my C: (OS) partition is growing daily with no obvious reasons. I tried to Rest/Refresh the Windows from PC Settings but it failed saying some files are missing and I need a installation media that I didn't have.

I followed one of the articles on web saying if everything fails then download Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaliation ISO and restore the recovery of Windows. I did that and was able to Refresh my PC.

Now after refresh its no more Windows 8 but Windows 8.1 Enterprise that needs activation. I do not have any recovery disk or product key of Windows 8.

Kindly help me to go back to my original OS Windows 8.

Comment: Did you create the Recovery Disks that you were advised to when you first bought the PC?

Comment: Well thats the sadest part. I did not. I'll answer my question below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is how I resolved it. I downloaded the Windows 8.1 recovery using [Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media). It downloads some files and you need to find "install.esd" under sources folder and convert it to "install.wim" using conversion tools like NtLite,Winreducer etc. I followed this [Article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) to mount the converted "install.wim" and then copy "winRE.wim" from mountedimage\windows\system32\recovery to my my system's C:\Windows\System32\Recovery folder to restore the Reset/Refresh mechanism of Windows and then copied "install.wim" on C:\ and pointed the Windows to this location to look for any files required for Reset/Refresh (as explained in the article)

After this I was able to refresh my system back to Windows 8.1 Single language.:)